# How can I store looped data into an array?

Tags: javascript

I want to store all the looped data into the `Course_Code` and `Grade` arrays.

Everything works except that only the last entered value is stored. What must I do to save all the data in the array?

```js
const MIN = 999;
const MAX = 10000;
const minLet = 64;
const maxLet = 91;
const GRADE_VALUE = 'parseInt(7)%parseInt(6)%parseInt(5)%parseInt(4)%parseInt(3)%parseFloat(1.5)';
var i;
var j;
var Grade = new Array();
var Course_Code = new Array();

while (willingnes != false) {
  var willingnes = confirm('Do you want to enter new Course Code? Click OK to continue or Cancel to stop?');

  if (willingnes == true) {

    Course_Code = prompt('Enter your Course Code', 'AAA1000');
    var Digits = parseInt(Course_Code.slice(-4)); // extract the last four digits from course code

    while (Course_Code.charCodeAt(0) < minLet || Course_Code.charCodeAt(0) > maxLet || Course_Code.charCodeAt(1) < minLet || Course_Code.charCodeAt(1) > maxLet || Course_Code.charCodeAt(2) < minLet || Course_Code.charCodeAt(2) > maxLet || isNaN(Digits) || Digits < MIN || Digits > MAX) {
      alert('Your input was invalid');
      Course_Code = prompt('Enter your Course Code', 'AAA1000');
    }

    Grade = prompt('Input a valid Course grade:');
    while (GRADE_VALUE.indexOf(Grade) < 0) {
      alert('Invalid Course value.');
      Grade = prompt('Re-enter valid course grade:');
    }
  }
}

alert(Course_Code);
alert(Grade);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning your array variables, you should use the push function to add the content.

Perhaps this would give you a better understanding of arrays:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Answer (score 0):

This is how you assign a code to an array:
First you check the value and then you add it to the array by pushing it.

What you were doing was just assigning a new value each time.

```
var code = prompt('Enter your Course Code', 'AAA1000');
if (code) {
    Course_Code.push(code);
}
```

for more info see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push